# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Book'

Tags: python, xlwings

I was following the instructions given in docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html. Probably, a trivial question but after running the RunPython sub in VBA, I get this error message:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "hello.py", line 12, in world
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Book'
```

FYI, I am using the Python Client v2.7.10 A3-VA and xlwings version is the 0.3.5. The hello.py file is in the same folder of the Excel file with the xlwings present. Let me know if you know how to solve the issue.
Thanks in advance!
Luca

Comment: Please also describe exact steps you have followed. E.g we don't know if and how did you install `xlwing` library. Did you use `conda` or `pip` or any other method? Please also check if this code works in standalone python. If so the problem might be with version of python you use in RunPython is not the one that you have xlwing installed.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the reply. The code does not work as standalone. If I run it with Spyder I get the same message error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Book'.

Comment: Did you install `xlwings` library at all?

Comment: Furthermore, xlwings has been directly installed with Python. I tried to re-install it but I get the message that the module is already present. The version of xlwings is the 0.3.5.

Comment: If I run the pip install xlwings in a command prompt, I get "Requirement already satisfied: xlwings in C:\...

Comment: Wow 0.3.5 is a quite old version. Current one is [0.10.1](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-10-1-dec-5-2016). Please try installing latest one: `pip install --upgrade xlwings`

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the feedback. I will update the version and come back with the outcome. Many thanks for the quick support!

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the late reply, but as running.t suggested, I was running a too old version of xlwings. In my version (0.3.5) the command is `xlwings.Workbook.caller()` instead of `xlwings.Book.caller()`.
Thanks again.